# How to fix error using java to run logisisim

Tags: java, macos

I am trying to open logisim with the following command

```
(base) MacBook-Pro-2:proj3 muaji$ java -jar tools/logisim-evolution.jar
```

I get this error, and am not sure what to do:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

# 

# SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x00007ff816429bc5, pid=3151, tid=259

# 

# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (21.0.1) (build 21.0.1)

# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (21.0.1, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, bsd-amd64)

# Problematic frame:

# C  \[AppKit+0xc92bc5\]  \_NSCarbonMenuCrashIfNeeded+0x258

# 

# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

# 

# An error report file with more information is saved as:

# /Users/muaji/Desktop/CS/proj3/hs_err_pid3151.log

# 

# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:

# https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues

# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.

# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

Abort trap: 6
```

Does anyone know what to do? I have already tried running "ulimit -c unlimited", and it doesn't seem to help. Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Why the `java-8` tag if you are using JDK 21? Why did you thought that the ulimit -c would be helpful? Have you tried with other JDK versions?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug in a an Apple component for macOS 14 Sonoma that impacts the Homebrew distribution of the JDK: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/150824.

Try some other distributions or a previous version of the JDK.